# MySQL errors with Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

When adding a new entity order and running the application i m getting this MYSQL error message in my cmd, can anyone please tell me why I am getting such an error.

```
| Error 2012-04-21 00:03:28,002 [Thread-7] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsucce
ssful: create table order (id bigint not null auto_increment, version bigint not
 null, customer_id bigint not null, item_id bigint not null, notes varchar(255)
not null, order_date datetime not null, order_price varchar(255) not null, qty v
archar(255) not null, taken_by varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=I
nnoDB
| Error 2012-04-21 00:03:28,006 [Thread-7] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - You hav
e an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL s
erver version for the right syntax to use near 'order (id bigint not null auto_i
ncrement, version bigint not null, customer_id b' at line 1
| Error 2012-04-21 00:03:28,008 [Thread-7] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsucce
ssful: alter table item add index FK317B13A35B400E (order_id), add constraint FK
317B13A35B400E foreign key (order_id) references order (id)
| Error 2012-04-21 00:03:28,009 [Thread-7] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - You hav
e an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL s
erver version for the right syntax to use near 'order (id)' at line 1
| Error 2012-04-21 00:03:28,011 [Thread-7] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsucce
ssful: alter table order add index FK651874E47370946 (item_id), add constraint F
K651874E47370946 foreign key (item_id) references item (id)
| Error 2012-04-21 00:03:28,013 [Thread-7] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - You hav
e an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL s
erver version for the right syntax to use near 'order add index FK651874E4737094
6 (item_id), add constraint FK651874E47370946 fo' at line 1
| Error 2012-04-21 00:03:28,016 [Thread-7] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsucce
ssful: alter table order add index FK651874EF3CCBB66 (customer_id), add constrai
nt FK651874EF3CCBB66 foreign key (customer_id) references customer (id)
| Error 2012-04-21 00:03:28,019 [Thread-7] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - You hav
e an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL s
erver version for the right syntax to use near 'order add index FK6

51874EF3CCBB6
6 (customer_id), add constraint FK651874EF3CCBB6' at line 1
```

Comment: dev environment? what version groovy/grails?, can you reformat the error message for readability?

Comment: @vector ..i m working on windows..grails 2.0.0...groovy 1.8.3....Here is the error   | Error 2012-04-21 00:03:28,002 '[Thread-7] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsucce
ssful: create table order (id bigint not null auto_increment, version bigint not
 null, customer_id bigint not null, item_id bigint not null, notes varchar(255)
not null, order_date datetime not null, order_price varchar(255) not null, qty v
archar(255) not null, taken_by varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=I'
nnoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot name a table `order` since it's a reserved word in SQL syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html. However you can change your table name to orders using mappings:

```
class Order {
    static mapping = {
        table "orders"
    }
}
```

Comment: you can escape it with backticks: ``table "`order`"``

Comment: @BurtBeckwith you're right, but I've heard opinion that it can still have issues in some cases so I didn't recommend it to beginner.

Comment: @sam1132 I'm glad it's working. You can accept an answer if it satisfy your needs. Thanks!